# Actions with strings, python

Tags: python, string

Okay, I need to change upper letters into lower, and lower ones into uppers, that's fine, but I also need to delete the first "i" letter and the last "i" letter from the sentence. Any ideas? Also, how do I print a text if there's no "i" letters in the input text? 
Thanks.

This is what I've got so far:

```
print("Write a sentence.")
sentence = input()

first = sentence.find("i")
second = sentence.rfind("i")

sentence.replace(first, " ")
sentence.replace(second, " ")

print(sentence.swapcase())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) with `count` argument, you can delete only *n* occurence of substring.

```
>>> sentence = 'Hello, This is string.'
>>> sentence = sentence.replace('i', '', 1) # Replace the first occurence of `i`
>>> sentence = sentence[::-1].replace('i', '', 1)[::-1] # reverse/replace/reverse
>>> sentence.swapcase()
'hELLO, tHS IS STRNG.'
```

NOTE: `str.replace` works case-sensitively. Above code only remove lower-case `i`.

---

Alternative using [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit). `str.*split` accepts optional `maxsplit` argument similar to `str.replace`:

```
>>> sentence = 'Hello, This is string.'
>>> sentence = ''.join(sentence.split('i', 1))
>>> sentence = ''.join(sentence.rsplit('i', 1))
>>> sentence.swapcase()
'hELLO, tHS IS STRNG.'
```

Comment: @user3143730, I just added an alternative. Check it out.